# Disable on-screen keyboard on Windows 7/8

Tags: windows-7, nsis, access-control, administrator, on-screen-keyboard

How can I rename a file in a system folder on Windows 7?

I tried `RequestExecutionLevel admin` directive, but it does not work. I cannot rename file even manually - there are no change permissions for Administrators. First you must change file owner, update permissions and only then you can rename a file.

What will be the command to change the file owner to Administrators? (or, is there another way to rename a file in a system folder on Windows 7?)

Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/777134/windows-7-kiosk-turn-off-screen-keyboadr-autostart

Comment: On newer versions of Windows there are almost no reasons to write to system32 at all. Are you installing a driver?

Comment: Which file are you trying to rename and why?

Comment: you can have the answer from the related question

Comment: The title of your question appears to be unrelated to the body.

Comment: Raymond, can you suggest proper one?

Answer (score 1):

If there is some setting in the Control panel that toggles the OSK autostart then finding the registry setting for that is probably the best option. Try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) or [RegShot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/).

Another alternative is adding something that runs at startup and kills osk.exe. Something as simple as a shortcut that executes taskkill.exe can be enough.

Renaming a system file is not something that I would recommend and to do it you would have to use the [AccessControl plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in) to change ownership etc.

Comment: Thanks for this info, I already tried procmon and there is another place in the registry that can be changed: this is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk. I am trying to change this section registry keys, but it also requires some poweruser permissions. So the question now is how to change this registry section keys.

Comment: AccessControl::SetRegKeyOwner + AccessControl::GrantOnRegKey but I would try to avoid doing this because it feels dirty messing with the system like this (IMHO). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb879984.aspx does not say these things run at startup as far as I can see...

Comment: Thanks, Anders! I totally agree with you, but after two days of comprehensive research it seems that this is the only way (except file renaming). I believe that you can do such things with caution if you understand what you are doing.

Can you give code example for AccessControl::SetRegKeyOwner + AccessControl::GrantOnRegKey? Is there a way to make the current user (without knowing the name) the owner?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15397451 and the readme that ships with the plugin. To get the current user you can use AccessControl::GetCurrentUserName.

Comment: It doesn't work. Return values are 'ok', but the registry in fact doesn't update.